Square3D Graphics Object
I wonder why there is no generalization of objects like Rectangle to Graphics3D included in the software. Does anybody know the reason for this?
Is it because the definitions of the parallel sides of the rectangle with respect to the 3D-space may differ to widely per user?
A very basic example would be this function for a square in 3D:
Square3D[centervec_,nvec_,parallelsidevec_,sidelength_]:=Block[{
(*parallelsidevecNORMALIZED*)nP=Normalize[parallelsidevec],
(*orthogonalsidevecNORMALIZED*)nV=Normalize[Cross[Normalize[parallelsidevec],Normalize[nvec]]]
},
Block[{
p1=centervec+sidelength/2*(nP+nV),
p2=centervec+sidelength/2*(nP-nV),
p3=centervec+sidelength/2*(-nP-nV),
p4=centervec+sidelength/2*(-nP+nV)
},
Polygon[{p1,p2,p3,p4,p1}]
]]

It allows to apply all styling attributes and transformations defined for the Polygon in 3D, without the need to specify the corner points directly, (and it's simplicity makes me ask this question).

Have you looked at Cuboid or Parallelpiped?

I don't think we can answer on why there is no such function. But note that there are two "similar" resource functions: Circle3D and Disk3D, but no Rectangle3D yet. You can make the function and publish it :)

@Domen Thank you for the Circle3D and Disk3D reference. Indeed, for if there comes up no reason I may do such publishing :)

@lericr Thank you for the reference to the Parallelepiped functionality with 2 vectors in 3D space, I oversaw this part. It certainly is the internal way to go.
